# Action when Form is closed c#

Tags: c#

I'm in College and this is my first (major) project.

I'm trying to perform an action when a form is closed. I don't seem to be getting the terminology right when searching online, or the answer given doesn't match what I want to do.

At the moment i'm declaring a Class and displaying the from -

```
private void createuser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User_Modification mod = new User_Modification("Create", "Create");
    mod.ShowDialog();
}
```

What I want to do is this -

```
WHEN mod IS CLOSED {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Loook at the events for the Form you should see things like closing, closed etc.

Comment: you tried searching online for "form closed C#" and you didn't get anything useful?

Comment: `ShowDialog` shows  a *modal* dialog box. You can start to "do stuff" the next line after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ShowDialog`, so the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed. `mod.ShowDialog(); doStuff();` will work pretty well.

Comment: Adding to Nadia's answer, you can set `DialogResult` in `User_Modication` and trap that value as the return value of the `ShowDialog()` call. This can be used as a success/failure flag to do other things. Return `OK` or `Cancel` as appropriate...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a handler to capture the FormClosed event:

In your constructor do:

```
this.FormClosed += Form_Closed;
```

Then in the body of your form, add this method.

```
private void Form_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
      // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: `.Closed` is an obsolete event.  .NET 2.0 introduced `.FormClosed`, which is what should be used now.

Answer (score 1):

You should attach handler to `FormClosed` event:

```
private void createuser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    User_Modification mod = new User_Modification("Create", "Create");
    mod.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(FormClosed);
    mod.ShowDialog();
}

void FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Closed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're using WinForms you can override `OnFormClosing` event:

```
  protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
       base.OnFormClosing(e);
       // your code...
  }
```

Comment: It is better practice to subscribe to the event unless you need to explicitly override behavior in OnFormClosing.  Two purposes should be two handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at two events:

`Form.FormClosing` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

`Form.FormClosed` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

First one will allow you to perform actions prior to the form being closed completely, such as canceling the closing procedure.  The second one is what you would use if you want to perform actions after the form is closed (perhaps to clean up resources, as an example).

So, as an example, let's say that you want to perform an action when the form is in fact closed:

```
// Somewhere in your code where you create the form object.
form.FormClosed += Form_FormClosed;

// Somewhere else in your code.
private void Form_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form closed");
}
```